# Returning list order to old index

Tags: java, list

I have an array of int that store old indexes of the list , i use it to restore data order in the list

```
int[] oldindex = function();
```

How the array work : the value of the oldindex array at index-n contains the index location of where the data at index-n is located before the operation.

For example , oldindex[0] contains the old index of current data at index 0.

I've tried switching data to restore the order . For example by creating a temporary variable to store the data at index n , then replace the data at index n with data at index k , and replace data at index k with data in temporary variable . Either i do it wrong or not but it does not work restoring the data order.

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.size();i++) {
  String temp = data.get(i);
  data.set(i, data.get(oldindex[i]));
  data.set(oldindex[i], temp);
}
```

Using temporary list to copy and reorder the data before returning it does work , but it cost too much memory for large data.

Is there any alternative to do this that is more efficient ?

Comment: Im on my phone sorry give a time for me to paste it as code from my laptop

Comment: *swapping* the data will not work here (can't read the code, based on text) - unless you also adjust the saved indexes ((like sorting the indexes and, in same way, changing value position))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simplified (naive) implementation:

```
    private static void order(String[] values, int[] old) {
        assert values.length == old.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            var nextv = values[old[i]];
            var nexti = old[old[i]];
            while (nexti != old[nexti]) {
                var tempv = values[nexti];
                var tempi = old[nexti];
                values[nexti] = nextv;
                old[nexti] = nexti;
                nextv = tempv;
                nexti = tempi;
            }
        }
    }
```

please see it as pseudo-code/idea only

Sample data/output:

```
start   values:   [D, G, C, E, H, A, F, J, I, B]
        oldindex: [3, 6, 2, 4, 7, 0, 5, 9, 8, 1]
result values:    [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]
        oldindex: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: yes , in the test code , "d" is currently at data[0] but it is previously at data[1] , if i make a mistake on my word in the question and confuses you feel free to edit it to what it should be

Comment: result of my code; `[b, d, c, a, e]` -  "d" is at its previous position, `data[1]`! so, what is wrong?

Comment: ah my bad , sorry , i repaired my test code and it worked , i made a mistake in the oldindex , it worked now ! thankss

Comment: although the answer is in array ,i can also apply same solution to list .

Comment: Note: `oldindex`  array is being changed by this!

Answer (score 1):

You pick up an element at some position 'p' and place it at the new, correct spot oldindex[p]. However, you don't want to overwrite the element on that position, so you need to copy it to a temporary variable. Now you need to find the correct position for this element, oldindex[oldindex[p]]. You store it there, but first save the element at that position to a temporary variable. You keep going, finding the correct spots for the elements and saving elements before overwriting them into a temporary variable, until you return to the initial position 'p' from which you started. At that moment you can just store the temporary variable into the list at position 'p', not worrying about overwriting it, because you have already moved that element to the correct spot. What you have achieved at that point is correct ordering of all elements in the list, which make a complete permutation cycle starting at index 'p'. Now you need to take next element which was not included in that permutation cycle and construct a new permutation cycle starting on that element, etc. However, you need to keep track which elements are already at correct positions and which are not. So, you'll still need a temporary space proportional to the size of the list O(n), which can be array of booleans. But I still recommend not to worry about the space occupied by references.

Comment: im sorry but do you mind adding some working example code ? this might take me some time/days to understand and test it , but if you can add working example code it will make it faster and easier to understand not just for me but also other people

Comment: Note: the old index list can be used to store the information if an elements position is already corrected, if that list can be re-used